# Can i control the keyboard from code on android in particular the caps lock

Tags: android, keyboard

Is it possible to popup the keyboard and set caps lock on from code on android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding add android:capitalize="characters" to the EditText properties. This should display the keyboard in CAPS.

Also FYI, this is how you show the keyboard via code:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make the keyboard default to all capital letters by using the [capitalize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3acapitalize) attribute:

```
 <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:capitalize="characters" />
```

Keep in mind that the user can simply turn "caps-lock" off. You can call [.toUpperCase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) on the String that you retrieve from the EditText.