# How to turn caps lock on of keypad Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can i control the keyboard from code on android in particular the caps lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746027/can-i-control-the-keyboard-from-code-on-android-in-particular-the-caps-lock)

I want to turn Caps lock on of a keypad on a text box focus in Phonegap Android. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but thats android native. I need the answer for Phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

A similar effect can be achieved on Android using CSS `text-transform: capitalize;` 
property on the input. This won't force the keyboard into SHIFT mode, instead it will force capitalization on the text box on blur. (In a desktop browser, the effect is immediate.) Values other than capitalize include uppercase and lowercase, which will force upper and lower case, respectively.

Comment: is it worked? If yes , please Accept my answer, so that someone will get help in future too

Comment: I tried your solution... On emulator it works fine but on device the word gets capitalize only when focus is lost from the text box and when focus is back on text box it again goes back to lowercase.

Comment: Is their any way I do it for phonegap?